# What is wrong with function `LetterCounts` and other functions that operate on strings?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, string-manipulation

I have noticed that many functions that are meant to operate on string are slower compared to similar functions that operate on lists.

One example: `Counts` versus `LetterCounts` (and notice that the version with `Counts` has to do two more tasks than version with `LetterCounts` - it has to do `ToCharacterCode` and then `KeyMap` with `FromCharacterCode` to transform the output to the `LetterCounts` version)

```
SeedRandom[1]
str = RandomInteger[{1, 26}, 300] /. 
    Thread[Range[26] -> CharacterRange["A", "Z"]] // StringJoin;

LetterCounts[str, 2] // RepeatedTiming

KeyMap[FromCharacterCode, 
  Sort[Counts[Partition[ToCharacterCode[str], 2, 1]], 
   Greater]] // RepeatedTiming

(*{0.00426, <|"TT" -> 3, "IF" -> 3, "EP" -> 3, ... , "HA" -> 1, "AH" -> 1, "FA" -> 1|>}*)
(*{0.000830, <|"TT" -> 3, "IF" -> 3, "EP" -> 3, ... , "HA" -> 1, "AH" -> 1, "FA" -> 1|>}*)
```

The speed difference is significant!

Something is rotten in the state of <strike>Denmark</strike> Wolfram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LetterCounts[str, 2]
```

and

```
KeyMap[FromCharacterCode, 
  Sort[Counts[Partition[ToCharacterCode[str], 2, 1]], Greater]];
```

are not equivalent operations - just try the inputs found in the [`LetterCounts`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LetterCounts.html) documentation and you'll quickly see differences.  So the timing comparison is not very meaningful.

edit: To answer the question in the comments, the self-written

```
myCharacterCounts[str_, n_] := KeyMap[FromCharacterCode,
    Counts @ Partition[ToCharacterCode @ str, n, 1]
]
```

will run slightly faster than `CharacterCounts[str, n]`, though on my machine the difference is sub-millisecond even for very large strings.

But this `myCharacterCounts` function **still** does not do everything that [`CharacterCounts`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CharacterCounts.html) does.

`CharacterCounts` takes options, as in

```
In[45]:= CharacterCounts["aAbBcC", IgnoreCase -> True]

Out[45]= <|"c" -> 2, "b" -> 2, "a" -> 2|>
```

and does argument checking, issuing a message for `CharacterCounts[]` or `CharacterCounts[2]`. Argument checking and options handling are generally required for any built-in system function, but not needed for self-written functions where you know you won't be passing bad arguments or options.  This may be enough to account for the timing difference, or maybe `CharacterCounts` is being inefficient somewhere - I can't say.

I will say that it is often, but not always, possible to beat the timing for built-in functions if you focus on a subset of the functionality and neglect error handling.  And if your application is time sensitive then it is worthwhile to use the custom function instead.

Comment: They are equivalent if you use both on strings that contain only letter characters... Further more you can replace `LetterCounts` with `Sort[CharacterCounts[#,2],Greater]&` and you get perfect equivalence for all strings inputs... and still `CharacterCounts` is slower the same way as `LetterCount` is compared to my code. Why would I ever use those functions when there is a faster method?

Comment: @azerbajdzan I don't understand your question.  `Sort[CharacterCounts[#,2],Greater]&` is also not equivalent to `LetterCounts`.  If you write a more specialized function that works better and faster for your inputs, then you should by all means use it.

Comment: That is not what I said. I said that `Sort[CharacterCounts[#,2],Greater]&` is equivalent with my code that uses `Counts`. And though they are equivalent my code is faster than when `CharacterCounts` is used and for no reason.

Comment: @azerbajdzan - had a long reply, added it to the answer instead.

Answer (score 4):

For short strings `LetterCounts` is slower, not sure why, for longer strings the timings are identical. Do you see similar behavior?

```
randomString[n_] := 
 RandomInteger[{1, 26}, n] /. 
   Thread[Range[26] -> CharacterRange["A", "Z"]] // StringJoin

counts[str_] := 
 KeyMap[FromCharacterCode, 
  Sort[Counts[Partition[ToCharacterCode[str], 2, 1]], Greater]]

<< GeneralUtilities`

BenchmarkPlot[{LetterCounts[#, 2] &, counts[#] &},
 randomString[#] &,
 10^Range[6],
 "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: On one string of length `10^6` I get `15` seconds for `LetterCounts` and `0.675` seconds for my code. So I do not think your plot express reality.

Comment: I think on your plot there is even missing red point at `10^6` for `LetterCounts` - probably `BenchmarkPlot` is not patient enough to wait `15` seconds for its evaluation so it plots it without it. When I run your code on my PC I get two almost parallel lines - red and blue if I connect those points.

Comment: Strange. On my Mac. `longString = randomString[1000000];`  `counts[longString]; // Timing` is `{1.79895, Null}` and `LetterCounts[longString, 2]; // Timing` is `{1.75694, Null}`.